# How to create Country, State, City and Zip Code field in D6

Tags: 6, nodes

I am having a registration page which contains the field Country, State, City and Zip Code Which needs to be hierarchical select.

My question may be very basic. But kindly clear it.

I have used content profile module to create all the registration fields.

**My question is what field type i need to give for the above fields what i mentioned (Country, State, City and Zip Code). Which needs to be hierarchical select.**

**Is there any examples or tutorials related to this topic will help a lot for me.**

Any help will be thankful and grateful.

thanks in advance..

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't used dedicated modules like [addresse](http://drupal.org/project/addresses) or [location](http://drupal.org/project/location) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Hierarchical Select Module](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) which works with Taxonomy Terms, Menus, User Profile Fields, Generic Lists and External APIs.  The field types you use for storage would not matter.

There are demos available on the [module developer's blog](http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select).

Warning: In the case of City Names and Zip Codes there is no hierarchy (at least in the States).  Many Zip Codes have multiple city names, many cities have multiple Zip Codes. For any hope of keeping this all current you'd have to use an external API.